# How do i remove number with brackets ?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, team-sites

[image]

How do I remove [2] it always showing on the page.

Comment: I think you might be having duplicate web part that might be hidden. Use '?contents=1' at the end of page url and see if there is similar web part and delete it.

Answer (score 3):

You can **'Edit Web Part'** and change the title of the Web Part under **Appearance**.

[image]

Edit Title Properties

[image]

You might have got two Web Part on the page so you can delete one and then change the title.  To delete the website you can open **Web Part Page Maintenance** by adding `?contents=1` so the the page url would be something like:

https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/SitePages/DevHome.aspx?contents=1

[image]

PS: For some reasons, I can't upload more screenshot but will trying again shortly.

Comment: could you please add more screenshots when you can

Comment: I tried twice last night but wasn't able to I will try again shortly.

Comment: @AY_91 I have now uploaded the screenshots. Hope this helps.